# scipy.integrate.odeint time dependend stepsize

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, odeint, timestep

I have the following problem:

I have to use an ode-solver to solve a chemical reaction equation. The rate constants are functions of time and can suddenly change (puls from electric discharge).

One way to solve this is to keep the stepsize very small `hmax < dt`. This results in a high comp. affort --> time consuming. My question is: Is there an efficient way to make this work? I thought about to `def hmax(puls_ON)` with `plus_ON=True` within the puls and `plus_ON=False` between. However, since dt is increasing in time, it may dose not even recognize the puls, because the time interval is growing hmax=hmax(t).

A time-grid would be the best option I thin, but I don't think this is possible with odeint?

Or is it possible to somehow force the solver to integrate at a specific point in time (e.g. t0 ->(hmax=False)->tpuls_1_start->(hmax=dt)->tpuls_1_end->(hmax=False)->puls_2_start.....)?

thx

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional parameter `tcrit` for the `odeint` that you could try:

> Vector of critical points (e.g. singularities) where integration care should be taken.

I don't know what it actually does but it may help to not simply step over the pulse.

If that does not work you can of course manually split your integration into different intervals. Integrate until your `tpuls_1_start`. Then restart the integration using the results from the previous one as initial values.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion with tcrit. However, odeint seems to be not the best method for this problem. I recognized on the scipy page they now suggest to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp instead of odeint? Finally, I think that VODE should be the best option for such ODE problems, since other plasma chemistry solver also use it. integrate.ode features VODE, but is it also fast? (comp. to odenit). And do you/anyone knows some examples, how to use it. It seems to be more tricky (have to calc jacobi...)? My odeint needs a lot of args, since df(t) depends on many time dependent parameter!

Comment: If you need the Jacobian you might want to have a look at how to symbolically represent your ODE and compute the Jacobian using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). The symbolic expression can then be converted to a python function. [Here](https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/32-chemical-kinetics-symbolic-construction.html) is an example (with odeint, but it should be similar with other solvers).